# Storing reply_channel

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have simple task of saving `reply_channel` in DB
But `message.reply_channel` has `class` type
Django Channels documentation says that `reply_channel` is

> unique pointer to the open WebSocket

So, how could I store this unique pointer in DB?